# Query many-to-many return null with two double many-many relationship

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core

I have a list of item, in which contain item that can be viewed by user with specific role or user who has been allowed to view that item. I try query a list of item for a user base on their role and their Id but it give ma null result. What did I do wrong here?

```
var query = from menuItem in _db.MenuItems
where menuItem.MenuRoles.Any(m => m.RoleId == role.Id)
where menuItem.MenuUsers.Any(m => m.UserId == userId)
select menuItem;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want a double where clause, you want or:

```cs
var query = from menuItem in _db.MenuItems
where menuItem.MenuRoles.Any(m => m.RoleId == role.Id) || menuItem.MenuUsers.Any(m => m.UserId == userId)
select menuItem;
```

If the first where doesn't find any, then your second where-clause isn't going to find anything in that result.
EDIT:
I just saw it's says *their role and their Id*. If so replace `||` with `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this query

```
var query = from menuItem in _db.MenuItems
where menuItem.MenuRoles.RoleId == role.Id && menuItem.MenuUsers.UserId == userId
select menuItem;
```